# How to set ScrollView's background color in NavigationView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I can't set a background color under `ScrollView` in SwiftUI. When I use `.background(Color.red)` the background is cut off so it doesn't go under navigation bar and scrolling seems to be broken. 
I tried a couple of solutions but each of them doesn't work.
I have a simple view hierarchy

```swift
NavigationView {
    ScrollView([.vertical], showsIndicators: true) {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0...50, id: \.self) { _ in
                Text("Text text")
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .large)
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

it works as expected

[image]

now, I would like to add a background color, I tried the following solutions

#### 1

```swift
NavigationView {
    ScrollView([.vertical], showsIndicators: true) {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0...50, id: \.self) { _ in
                Text("Text text")
            }
        }
    }
    .background(Color.red)
    .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .large)
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

result

[image]

#### 2

```swift
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        Color.red
        ScrollView([.vertical], showsIndicators: true) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0...50, id: \.self) { _ in
                    Text("Text text")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .large)
    }
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

result

[image]

#### 3

```swift
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.all])
        ScrollView([.vertical], showsIndicators: true) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0...50, id: \.self) { _ in
                    Text("Text text")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .large)
    }
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

result

[image]

How to set up a background color under `ScrollView` packed in `NavigationView`?

// edit:

The animation below presents a desirable effect (it is made with UIKit).

[image]

Comment: I have also the same issue. Seems like another SwiftUI Bug.

Comment: Even if I put the scrollView into a ZStack { Color.red, ScrollView } I have the same problem.

Comment: Did u find any solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I had abandoned SwiftUI and switched to UIKit. SwiftUI is incomplete and can't be used in production...

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 7):

After exhausting all possibilities, I landed with the below solution which works perfectly for what you want to achieve.

```
struct DemoView: View {
    
    init(){
        let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        UIScrollView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
                ScrollView{
                    VStack{   
                        ForEach(0..<30, id: \.self){ _ in
                                Text("Text Text").foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        }
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                     .background(Color(UIColor.red))
            
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title")
        }  
    }
}
```

Hope this helps;)

Comment: But what if I wanted to implement a dark theme as well?

Comment: @leonboe If you add a background color to a view, then your dark theme will carry the same color set by you as the background color(not the dark color). Only the default colors will carry the dark color if you set a dark theme.

Comment: And it’s not possible to change the background color if a switch from dark mode -> light mode and vice versa has been detected?

Comment: Once the background color is set, the light or dark mode will not make a difference. It will altogether carry the same color you set.

Comment: Warning for anyone using Xcode 12 / SwiftUI 2 ... adding .padding() to anything outside the ScrollView will broke the fix above for my project. Padding had to be added to elements within the ScrollView, then this worked. This is obviously a convenient feature of a well-baked framework.

Comment: This is not a good answer as this change is global

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve nearly the same behaviour using the code below which uses List View.

```
struct DemoView: View {
    init(){
        let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
 
                List{

                    ForEach(0..<30, id: \.self){ _ in
                        
                        Text("Text Text")
                        
                    }.listRowBackground(Color(UIColor.red))
            }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title")
        }
        
    }
}
```

The code produces these views :[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ymVw.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKbIF.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is a hacky SwiftUI solution:

**iOS 13 and iOS 14**

```swift
NavigationView {
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            // ...
        }
        .background(Color.red.frame(height: 99999999))
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. The red background extends to the top and bottom correctly but is not wide enough to fill the whole screen.

Comment: Downvoted: You should never hardcode a height or any measurement with a number like that. Please, do not use this code.

Comment: if you are going to use a set frame here, at least use a `GeometryReader` to determine the frame height.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After the `.background()` modifier I added `.padding(.top)` and it worked as it should.

Answer (score 1):

This works (see [details](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-list-background-color/)):

```
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
    VStack {
        ForEach(0...70, id: \.self) { _ in
            Text("Text text")
        }
    }
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
}
.background(.pink)
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        //Use this if NavigationBarTitle is with Large Font
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .red
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView([.vertical], showsIndicators: true) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(0...70, id: \.self) { _ in
                        Text("Text text")
                    }
                }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color(UIColor.red))
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .large)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

It would produce a view that looks like this:
[image]

[image]

I know it's not the full solution because of the top safe edge, but hopefully it helps you get a little closer.

PS Ive tried ignoring the top safe edge but it causes issues with nav bar spacing

Comment: This is a kind of hack, this doesn't work in the way as it should. I don't want to change navigation bar's color, what if my background would be an image or gradient? I feel that SwiftUI smells bad.

Comment: Haha, SwiftUI hasn't been fully developed.