# Change Background Color of ScrollView SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, background-color

I am new to developing IOS apps and I am having problems with extra whitespace at the bottom of my login page depending on the size of the image that I have on the screen. I have been told that I should change the background color of my ScrollView and set my view's background as clear. I am not sure about how to change the background color of the ScrollView. My code basically looks like this with some stuff removed for readability:

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        //if login.isLoggedIn {
        MainView()
        //} else {
        VStack() {
            
        }
        
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color{.lightblue), Color(.blue)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
        }
}
//}
```

[image: Screen with Whitespace]
[image: Screen without Whitespace After Image on Screen is Made Larger]

Can someone show me how to change the background color? I would prefer the background color to be that of the linear gradient above. If not, can you show how to do this in UIScrollView?

Comment: Are you sure that your code runs? It seems like it has a bunch of errors like `Color{blue)` and `CColor(blue)`. Is `CColor` a type from imported library? Also why are you passing `blue` color in both places? And it should be `.blue` unless you have defined it like `let blue: CGColor = .blue` somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @ParthTamane Yes, it runs. I just typed it incorrectly. The blues are two different shades and are actually blue boxes/color boxes. I forget what they are called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving the background colour setting one line below. Also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58519018/how-to-set-scrollviews-background-color-in-navigationview-in-swiftui) might be helpful.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            //if login.isLoggedIn {
            MainView()
            //} else {
            VStack() {
                
            }
        }.background(
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(.lightblue), Color(.blue)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        ).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

...

// Extension for custom colour lightBlue
extension UIColor {
    static let lightBlue = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.6, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1)
}
```

Comment: I accidently attempted to edit your answer instead of my original post.